# DNSmasq Forward DNS on Multiple Interfaces

Tags: wifi, dnsmasq, hostapd

I am using `hostapd` to setup WiFi hotspot networks on my Ubuntu 18.04. I am using [this guide](http://wiki.stocksy.co.uk/wiki/Multiple_SSIDs_with_hostapd) to setup multiple SSIDs on my WiFi interface. And to enable DHCP on the hotspot networks, I use `dnsmasq`.

I run a separate instance of `dnsmasq` for each SSID. Now, I have multiple Ethernet interfaces available on this computer and I want each `dnsmasq` instance to forward the DNS requests it receives on a different Ethernet interface.

Is there an easy way to do this? In other words, is there a way to tell `dnsmasq` which Ethernet interface to use for forwarding DNS queries? I know that in theory I can use network namespaces to do this, but I'm looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use this `dnsmasq` option `--server=10.1.2.3@ethX` where `ethX` is the Ethernet interface to use. I tested it and it works fine.